# After running a regression, should you comment on the signs of the coefficients on your control variables?

Tags: econometrics

I am looking at the impact of student debt on entrepreneurship. In my model, I control for various things like gender, race, age, etc. When I ran my regression, I found that several of these variables had statistically significant and interesting effects. It seems like convention is to not talk about controls in the 'discussion' section of the paper. Should I follow this convention and avoid mentioning what I think are some interesting effects?

Comment: You can talk about anything you want as long as you can make up a good story. That's all they care about. In the end you can't really measure that impact. If I didn't have a student loan it could mean that I didn't go to a college or dropped out, and went to run my own business like Elizabeth Holms. How are you going to account for this? Or, if maybe I went to college and accumulated a big loan at relatively low APR. I wasn't drinking in the college like everyone else, instead studied and learned a lot, then started my own business, and don't want to pay off my loan yet. How to control this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't. I even go so far as to suppress the coefficients/mean difference for adjustment values and note in the footnotes that those variables were adjusted in the model(s).

As I see it, the model that you fit is not meant to estimate those associations in any valid way, but rather to use those covariates to adjust the expected outcome so that the comparison of the main exposure: entrepreneurship is valid and efficient. A problem arises when a reviewer or reader interprets those findings in the latter sense and is miffed when the reported findings contradict their expectation based on experiential knowledge/other data analyses.

It introduces other statistical issues as well, such as multiple testing, but most importantly, it muddies the notion that you have a central, primary hypothesis that motivated the data analysis.

Comment: In what sense these other associations "cannot be estimated in any valid way", while the "primary" association can? It has been designated as "primary" in a totally arbitrary way, by "decree" of the researcher. I might as well declare that I want to study the effect of gender on entrepreneurship, and suddenly, by your  logic the association with gender is the one validly estimated while the association with debt is not, with the exact same model and the exact same data.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos a main exposure would be a mediator in a causal model relating a confounder W to an outcome. There could be other confounders, like Z, that would need to be added to a second model, but weren't considered in the first model since W satisfied the backdoor criterion.